# How to redirect the user to another page when he is refreshing the page or coming back

Tags: php, redirect, refresh

I'm currently working on a game and I've a big problem because I've checked the similar questions but I didn't find any answer.

I would like the user to be redirect automatically to another page in the case he click on the button to refresh the page and in the case he click on the button in order to coming back to the last page.

Could you please explain me ?

Is it possible to do this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Yesh it is possible with **jquery** you can use set time out and

**window.location.replace/href**

function for this .